# Peripherals not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. Since then, every time I want to log into my user account the mouse and keyboard suddenly stop working. I've tried rebooting with no luck. Both the mouse and the keyboard work just fine before I log into my user account.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: I dropped to root shell prompt and created a new user from there with the command "adduser", re-booted and logged into the new user account. The second I press enter after typing the password I get a black screen for a couple of seconds and get redirected to the initial user login screen.

Comment: Your user account is probably corrupted. Try creating a new user with similar privileges as you (admin, I'd guess) and see if the same happens. You could also begin with looking at `$ dmesg -e > foobar` Please report here with relevant info, by editing yr initial post so people can start thinking about yr pbm. Right now you have provided insufficient info.

Comment: I dropped to root shell prompt and created a new user from there. After that, I tried booting into ubuntu again. The user I had created with the root shell prompt was there. I tried to log in to it only to get directed to the screen where you pick a user account. After doing this a bunch of times with the same result, I decided to try to log in to my previous account and the result was the same as before. My peripherals stopped working the second I logged in

Comment: You're missing essential elements of yr base Ubuntu configuration. You can troubleshoot this, but it'll take time.  Reinstalling a clean OS might be a better option. In doing so, you will learn less but you will definitely save time... This said, can you check yr `/etc/default/useradd` and `/etc/login.defs` files and post contents in OP ? You should see HOME, GROUP, SKEL and SHELL default variables there.  If re-installing is not an option, create a new user from root shell with `useradd -m -d /home/USERNAME -s /bin/bash USERNAME`. User's UID, group and GID should be dealt with automatically.

Comment: Reinstalling is an option, but I'd like to take the time to fix it. Can you tell me which command I need to use to check /etc/default/useradd and /etc/login.defs from the root shell prompt?

Comment: Yr position is quite defendable, but if you are new to any type of shell, troubleshooting this faulty install might not be the most efficient way to learn yr way around.  To visualize any file in terminal ,do `# less path/filename` as root or `$sudo less path/filename` as a normal user.  Press `space-bar` to advance one screen at a time, `b` to backtrack one screen and `q` to quit that page display mode. (There are many tutorials on the net on basics). Trouble-shooting yr issue will be way more complex. Hence my suggestion to reinstall. How did you install in the first place ?

Comment: I had installed 16.04, then I upgraded to 17.04 (no issues so far) and right after that to 18.04 .

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu 18.04 as you suggested because my parents wanted to use it. Although its responsiveness is unbearably slow. Even slower than Windows 7. Is it a hardware issue.? CPU: FX-4300 3.8GHz iGPU:ATI 3000 My HDD is a bit old so that is the most sensible cause, but I don't think it makes sense for it to be so much slower than Windows